# findAll() fails to find any elements within a given parent element

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull gene sequences from the NCBI website using Python and BeautifulSoup.

Upon viewing the HTML from the sequence page, I noticed that the sequence is stored within `span` elements stored within a `pre` element stored within a `div` element.

I've used the `findAll()` function in an attempt to pull the string contained inside the `span` element, but the `findAll()` function returns an empty list. I've attempted to use the `findAll()` function on the parent `div` element, and, whilst it returns the `div` element in question, it contains none of the HTML inside the `div` element; furthermore, the `div` element returned by the `findAll()` function is somewhat "corrupted" in that some of the attributes within the opening `div` tag are either missing or not in the correct order as given on the HTML webpage.

The following sample code is representative of the scenario:

**Actual HTML:**

```
<div id=viewercontent1 class="seq gbff" val=*some_value* sequencesize=some_sequencesize* virtualsequence style="display: block;">
    <pre>
        "*some gene information enclosed inside double quotation marks*
        "
        <span class="ff_line", id=*some id*>*GENETIC SEQUENCE LINE 1*</span>
        <span class="ff_line", id=*some id*>*GENETIC SEQUENCE LINE 2*</span>
        ...
        <span class="ff_line", id=*some id*>*GENETIC SEQUENCE LINE N*</span>
    </pre>
</div>
```

**My Code Snippets:**

The object of my code is to pull the string contents of the `pre` element (both the `span` strings and the opening string beginning, "*some gene information...").

```
# Assume some predefined gene sequence url, gene_url.

page = urllib2.urlopen(gene_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
spans = soup.findAll('span',{'class':'ff_line'})
for span in spans:
    print span.string
```

This prints nothing because the `spans` list is empty. Much the same problem occurs if a `findAll` is applied to `pre` instead of `span`.

When I try to find the parent `div` element using the same procedure as above:

```
# ...
divs = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'seq gbff'})
for div in divs:
    print div
```

I get the following print output:

```
<div class="seq gbff" id="viewercontent1" sequencesize="*some_sequencesize*" val="*some_val*" virtualsequence=""></div>
```

The most obvious difference is that the printed result doesn't contain any of the nested HTML, but also the content within the opening `div` tag is also different (arguments are either missing or in the wrong order). Compare with equivalent line on webpage:

```
<div id=viewercontent1 class="seq gbff" val=*some_value* sequencesize=some_sequencesize* virtualsequence style="display: block;">
```

Has this issue got something to do with the `virtualsequence` argument in the opening `div` tag?

How can I achieve my desired aim?

Comment: Try this ans, this will hep to you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466900/why-urllib-urlopen-read-does-not-correspond-to-source-code/21276452#21276452

Answer (score 2):

Class is a reserved keyword in Python (used when creating objects), so maybe this is causing the trouble, you can try to follow it by underscore and passing it as keyword argument, perhaps this will help:

```
>>> soup.find_all('span',class_='ff_line')
```

[Check out the docs.](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class)